# Replace attribute value with non NULL values from a joined attribute column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a Geodatabase with a column for pipe diameter. I have a secondary data set with field verified data and a column for pipe diameter. I would like to replace the pipe diameter in the Geodatabase with that in the secondary data set using the Python Parser in the Field Calculator. I have joined the secondary data set to the geodatabase and have many NUll values associated with pipes that have not yet been field verified.

Through online research, without finding anything specific, I have hodgepodged the following:

```
def IgnoreNull (GravitySewer.Diameter, assets.Diameter)
 if assets.Diameter is None:
      return GravitySewer.Diameter
 else:
      return assets.Diameter
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Does it work?  Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I created a feature class with some features with diameter values and a table with some other diameters

[image]

These I joined together.  You can see that feature `1` should not update due to the `NULL` in, but features `2` and `3` should both update

[image]

Using the following code I updated the feature class diameters from the joined table, only if the joined table value was not `NULL`

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```py
def ignore_null(grav_diam, assets_diam):
    x = grav_diam
    if assets_diam:
        x = assets_diam
    return x
```

Expression:

```py
ignore_null( !GravitySewer.Diameter!, !assets.Diameter!)
```

[image]

The result:

[image]

And with the join removed:

[image]

Comment: I didn't see this post and I reposted the question with a little more depth. The solution that worked for me can be found in "[Recalculate a Field with data from another field, ignoring NULL values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262073/recalculate-a-field-with-data-from-another-field-ignoring-null-values)". I am not sure how to delete this question. Turns out that the coding I had was generally correct, I was missing a : on the the first line.